# CSS Module Lit Element Bootstrap 5 default font

Tags: bootstrap-5, css-modules, lit-element

I have bootstrap loaded in a lit-element css module - bootstrap floating form labels are working fine, but the font looks like times new roman.  Linking normal css file as a link in the light dom in index.html "fixes" the problem.  Wondering if anyone has come across this?

Here is my web component:

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';
import bsstyle from './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.js';
class TestBlank extends LitElement { 
  static styles = [bsstyle];
  render() {
    return html`
    <h1>TestLit Shadow DOM, bootstrap loaded as css module</h1>
      <form>
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" 
          placeholder="placeholder..."
          .value=""
          id="datainput"
        >
        <label class="form-label" for="datainput">Floating Label</label>        
      </div>
      </form>
    `
  } 
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
} customElements.define('test-blank', TestBlank);
```

My bootstrap.min.css.js looks like (truncated):

```
import { css } from 'lit-element';
export default css`
@charset "UTF-8";/*!
 * Bootstrap v5.1.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2021 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2021 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
 */:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-white:#fff
...
```

The font in the , , and any text entered into the form field shows times-new-roman (not bootstrap).  But the floating form works fine.  So the lit element css module of bootstrap.min.css.js must be working somewhat.

Adding a in page css class enclosed in a  tag to the render() also "fixes" the problem:

```
render() {
  return html`
  <style>
    .labelfont {
      font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";        
      color: #666;
    }
  </style>
...
and
<label class="form-label labelfont" for="datainput">Floating Label</label>
```

But would rather have the css module just work entirely.  Thanks!

Comment: In case it matters, my html starts with:<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">

Comment: also, in case it matters, I'm using webpack